# How to do paging on Object that isn't Entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, paging

I'm trying to do paging, very similar to the option of @RepositoryRestResource
but only on object that isn't Entity.

the code:

```
public class FloorplanDevice {

private String FloorplanName;
private Long FloorplanId;

private Long DeviceId;
private String DeviceName;
private String macAddress;
private Long groupId;
private LocatableType deviceType;

public String getFloorplanName() {
    return FloorplanName;
}

public void setFloorplanName(String floorplanName) {
    FloorplanName = floorplanName;
}

public Long getFloorplanId() {
    return FloorplanId;
}

public void setFloorplanId(Long floorplanId) {
    FloorplanId = floorplanId;
}

public Long getDeviceId() {
    return DeviceId;
}

public void setDeviceId(Long deviceId) {
    DeviceId = deviceId;
}

public String getDeviceName() {
    return DeviceName;
}

public void setDeviceName(String deviceName) {
    DeviceName = deviceName;
}

public String getMacAddress() {
    return macAddress;
}

public void setMacAddress(String macAddress) {
    this.macAddress = macAddress;
}

public Long getGroupId() {
    return groupId;
}

public void setGroupId(Long groupId) {
    this.groupId = groupId;
}

public LocatableType getDeviceType() {
    return deviceType;
}

public void setDeviceType(LocatableType deviceType) {
    this.deviceType = deviceType;
}

public FloorplanDevice() {
}

public FloorplanDevice(String floorplanName, Long floorplanId, Long deviceId, String deviceName, String macAddress, Long groupId, LocatableType deviceType) {
    FloorplanName = floorplanName;
    FloorplanId = floorplanId;
    DeviceId = deviceId;
    DeviceName = deviceName;
    this.macAddress = macAddress;
    this.groupId = groupId;
    this.deviceType = deviceType;
  }
}
```

This object **doesn't have Repository** but it has controller:

```
   @RequestMapping(
      path = arrayOf("/floorplanDevice/{groupId}", "/floorplanDevice/{groupId}/"),
      method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
 open fun getFloorplanDevice(@PathVariable("groupId") groupId: Long): ResponseEntity<*>{

var floorplanDevice= floorplanService.getFloorplanDevice(groupId)
return ResponseEntity(floorplanDevice, HttpStatus.OK)

 }
```

So how can I do Paging to this object with page number and size (if it possible sorting also)?

I'm using java Spring

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public Page<FloorplanDevice> getFloorplanDevice(@PathVariable("groupId") Long groupId, 
            @PageableDefault Pageable pageable)
    List<FloorplanDevice> list = floorplanService.getFloorplanDevice(groupId);

    MutableSortDefinition sort = pageable.getSort() != null ?
            StreamSupport.stream(pageable.getSort().spliterator(), false)
                .findFirst()
                .map(it -> new MutableSortDefinition(it.getProperty(), it.isIgnoreCase(), it.isAscending()))
                .orElse(null)
            : null;

    PagedListHolder<FloorplanDevice> pageHolder = new PagedListHolder<>(list, sort);
    pageHolder.setPage(pageable.getPageNumber());
    pageHolder.setPageSize(pageable.getPageSize());
    pageHolder.resort();

    List<FloorplanDevice> content = pageHolder.getPageList();
    Page<FloorplanDevice> page = new PageImpl<>(content, pageable, list.size());

    return page;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. I have another one, Ill post it now

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
This is my solution by using PageListHolder.

```
     @RequestMapping(
      path = arrayOf("/floorplanDevice/{groupId}/page/{pageNum}/size/{sizeNum}", "/floorplanDevice/{groupId}/page/{pageNum}/size/{sizeNum}/"),
      method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET))
open fun getFloorplanDevicePage(@PathVariable("groupId") groupId: Long, @PathVariable("pageNum") pageNum: Int,@PathVariable("sizeNum") sizeNum: Int): ResponseEntity<*>{

var floorplanDevice= floorplanService.getFloorplanDevice(groupId)
var paging= PagedListHolder<FloorplanDevice>(floorplanDevice)
var setsize= paging.setPageSize(sizeNum)
if(paging.pageCount>pageNum){
var setpage=paging.setPage(pageNum)}
else{
  return throw RuntimeException("page: $pageNum is too big, insert smaller page from 0 to ${paging.pageCount-1}")
  }
var pageList= paging.pageList
return ResponseEntity(pageList, HttpStatus.OK)

}
```